# Flutter in_app_purchase return wrong inapp prices

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm using in_app_purchase 3.0.6 package but i get wrong prices for the inapp i have created in Google Play e AppStoreConnect.
On AppStoreConnect i have 3 inapp with those settings :

```
1 - identifier: com.inapp_1   , tier 1  ( 0,99 € )
 
2 - identifier: com.inapp_2   , tier 2  ( 1,99 € )

3 - identifier: com.inapp_3   , tier 3  ( 2,99 € )
```

On Google Play i have those settings :

```
1 - identifier: com.inapp_1   ( 0,99 € )
 
2 - identifier: com.inapp_2   ( 1,99 € )

3 - identifier: com.inapp_3   ( 2,99 € )
```

with this code i retrive the inapp prices to show the product:

```
 final ProductDetailsResponse response = await InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails(inappidentifier);
    
 if (response.notFoundIDs.isNotEmpty) {
     //empty
 } else {
     List<ProductDetails> products = response.productDetails;
     final ProductDetails productDetails = products[0];
     //ProductDetails contains the informations i need to use 
 }
```

the prices i retrive from ProductDetailsResponse are:

```
on IOS :

1 - identifier: com.inapp_1   ( 1,09 € )
 
2 - identifier: com.inapp_2   ( 2,49 € )

3 - identifier: com.inapp_3   ( 3,49 € )


on Android :

1 - identifier: com.inapp_1   ( 1,19 € )
 
2 - identifier: com.inapp_2   ( 2,39 € )

3 - identifier: com.inapp_3   ( 3,69 € )
```

Those prices are extracted from `productDetails!.rawPrice` and it seems the real price user will pay if complete the transaction (At least it is the price i see in the native device dialog during payment).

The currency is € and that's correct.

I can't find anything in docs that can justify those strange prices. How i can do to retrive the prices i set in Google Play and AppStoreConnect?